# Music brings monsters

Tags: episode-identification, story-identification

There was an *Outer Limits*, *Twilight Zone*, or *Night Gallery* episode (definitely in color) where a town didn't allow music or singing because they believed it would bring the monsters out.

The newcomer to the town asked if anyone had ever seen the monster. To which they all responded "no because we don't allow singing". "Maybe you haven't seen them because they don't exist". Of course he gets everyone to join in a song which promptly gets everyone killed as the monsters descend upon them.

I can't remember the name of this episode or even the series. Does this ring a bell with anybody?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Night Visions, an episode titled [*Harmony*](https://web.archive.org/web/20130604044624/http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-4672/episodes/126952/).

> Tired from traveling, Eli West decides to stop off in a small town called Harmony. It's a nice little town, with friendly residents and a good community. There is just one odd thing about it- music, all types of music, is completely prohibited. When Eli asks for reasons, he is told that a mysterious and deadly "Beast" lives on the outskirts of town and it is attracted by music. Laughing at the legend, Eli attempts to prove the townspeople wrong... however, is he dismissing the legend too hastily?

Comment: That's the one exactly! Thanks a million.